# Bootstrap 4 small badge next to big title

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a *small* Bootstrap (4) badge next to a *big* title. What i've tried:

```
<h1>Product <span class="badge badge-primary">Version 1</span></h1>
```

[image]

and

```
<h1>Product></h1>
<span class="badge badge-primary">Version 1</span
```

[image]

What I want:

[image]

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like

```
<div>
  <h1 style="display: inline-block">Product</h1>
  <span class="badge badge-primary" style="vertical-align: top">Version 1</span>
</div>
```

might do the trick.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 27):

A cleaner approach would be to use the Bootstrap 4 utility classes that have been provided:

```
<h2 class="h3 d-inline-block">Product</h2>
<span class="badge badge-primary align-top">Version 1</span>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Reading Material**

[`display`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

[`vertical-align`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/)

Comment: Except this can mess with other elements layout, for instance if you have an image over the h2 title

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the size of the pill? Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64633073/5783745

Answer (score 1):

You should use the first version:

```
<h1>Product <span class="badge badge-primary">Version 1</span></h1>
```

And apply the following styles on `.badge`

```
font-size: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
top: 10px; //depends on your font-size
position: relative;
```

Comment: Upvote. When used in li a header, had only to set line-height:0.6 and classes "badge badge-primary align-top"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you're using Bootstrap, you can also control the size of the badge using the css "text-small", "text-medium" or "text-large". Example:

```html
<div>
  <h1 style="display: inline-block">Product</h1>
  <span class="badge badge-primary text-medium" style="vertical-align: top">Version 1</span>
</div>
```