# Decrease font size for a badge in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Is it possible to decrease text size of a *badge*?

```
<div class="card-header border-0">
    <h3>
        <span>Some name</span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">Some status</span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I want text "Some status" to be h5 or h6

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405941/bootstrap-4-small-badge-next-to-big-title

Comment: yes thank you! please close